# Use a gulp task in mulitple projects

Tags: git, npm, gulp, bower, git-submodules

I have a gulp task that generates favicons. I'd like to reuse this task across several projects. It's based on the gulp file that realfavicongenerator.net outputs.

How can I approach this? The favicon generator task is a git repo, could it be referenced as a submodule in my other projects git repos? Or should I be looking to generate this as a npm or bower package.

I'd like to be able to pass some options to the generator task to override default settings.

I'm not sure where to start, any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Was my answer of any help? If not, would you mind giving us some feedback on your needs? If you found a different answer, it's encouraged to write and accept it.

Comment: Hi Emile, I started to look at this and made some headway, but I had to leave this for now due to work priorities, I'll let you know how i get on - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made reusable gulp tasks since we had multiple frontend projects all using gulp. The best way I found was to create a private npm package that I add in the other projects with its git URL.

## Build a Node.js module of shareable tasks

All you need is a repo with a `index.js` and a `package.json`. Install the necessary gulp dependencies and save them in the package file.

In the `index.js`, export the functions you want to reuse as tasks.

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    args = require('yargs').argv;

module.exports = {
    concat: function(src, dest, options) {
        return gulp.src(src)
            .pipe(gulpif(args.prod, concat()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
    }
};
```

Since this module will be using most dependencies required to make the tasks, your other projects dependencies will shrink to the minimum they explicitly need.

## Use your tasks module

Then, in your other projects, install the package with its git URL.

```
npm install --save-dev git+ssh://git@github.com:onebitrocket/onebitrocket-gulp-utils.git
```

*This git url format also works with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/fr/).*

And in your project's `gulpfile.js`, just use it.

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      onebitrocket = require('onebitrocket-gulp-utils');

// use a function which returns the result of your util.
gulp.task('js', () => onebitrocket.concat('src/**/*.js', 'www/'));
```

*Note: it's not needed to publish the package to the npm registry in order to use it. All you need is read access rights to the repo.*

Comment: I finally go round to working on this. Works well. For what it's worth i'm  abstracting out the gulp task generated by realfavicongenerator in to a reusable module across several projects that require the same output.